# Wireless not Working on Dell Latitude D430

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have recently installed version 12.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude D430. I have tried to get the [wireless card](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Dell_Wireless_1395_(DW1395)) (which appears to use the Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 chip) to work for the past 3 days and I have been unsuccessful. I installed all the recent updates. For some reason the OS is not recognizing the driver for the wireless card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 4):

Try this for a for your D430

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Scott, thank you so much for your help it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
sudo su
echo b43 >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Comment: How this will solve OP's problem?

Comment: as per thread below, it worked for me and for others too...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1975503&page=2

Answer (score 0):

Even after all the passed time since you've wrote your question, I decided to answer it to help others that might have the same difficulty with the wireless card not being recognized.

I have a laptop Dell Latitude D830 with Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Minicard (chipset Broadcom BCM 4311 802.11 b/g) and did the following, similar to Scott Goodgame's sugestion, to solve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree    
sudo reboot
```

An alternative way to do this changes, using 'Synaptic', where described by me with more details at:

https://askubuntu.com/a/428695/254056

The Broadcom's driver 'bcmwl-kernel-source', which is automatically installed by Ubuntu, is involved in some bugs with the kernel. It has been reported issues with many device models, Ubuntu versions and kernel versions. More informations about this issue can be found at the link below:

https://askubuntu.com/a/428702/254056

Cheers!!

Comment: Answer update: apparently, at least with Ubuntu 14.04, it's not necessary to install the package 'linux-firmware-nonfree'. Removing completely 'bcmwl-kernel-source' and installing 'b43-fwcutter' and it's dependant 'firmware-b43-installer' is enough to fix the problem.