# wlan device disappear (BCM43142)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10

```
$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i distrib
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"

$ lspci | grep -i bcm
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

$ lshw -c network
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f1900000-f1907fff

$ lsmod | grep -i bcma
bcma                   46670  0 

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep -i wlan

$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:40211 (40.2 KB)  TX bytes:40211 (40.2 KB)
```

seems like the module for the wifi is not loaded (or loaded incorrectly).
i will appreciate if one could shed the light on the issue and assist bringing the wifi up again.

also tried

```
$ rmmod bcma
$ modprobe bcma
```

but it did not help

**update:** i did the following and it seems to help. can it be?

```
$ apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to update your Ask Ubuntu's account profile and provide a name and a picture so others can know who they are talking to. This data are shown below a question, answer or comment made by you in order to identify your self.

Problems concerning Broadcom wireless cards not being recognized, panicing the kernel and other compatibility issues, happends on a regular basis. The source may be the Broadcom's package/driver called 'bcmwl-kernel-source', which is automaticaly installed by Ubuntu. Check out what I've written at the link below, and also at the links pointed by it, to see if the case described is the same you're experiencing.

https://askubuntu.com/a/428712/254056

At the end, don't forget to give us a feedback and help the community!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with Lubuntu 15.10:

```
fred@fred-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /etc/*release*|grep DISTRIB
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
```

lspci and lshw output seems ok:

```
$ lspci | grep -i bcm
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
   description: Network controller
   produit: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   fabriquant: Broadcom Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 01
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   ressources: irq:18 mémoire:b5500000-b5507fff
(...)
```

But I found something strange with bcma module

```
$ lsmod | grep bcma
$
```

Bcma was not loaded so I did

```
$ sudo modprobe bcma
```

And then I got

```
$ lsmod | grep bcma
bcma                   53248  0
```

But still "Used by" column is at 0

rfkill list show only bluetooth:

```
$ rfkill unblock wlan
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg shows nothing about wlan but it seems that there is an error with firmware load for BCM:

```
fred@fred-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ dmesg | grep -i wlan
fred@fred-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ dmesg | grep -i bcm
[    2.586276] usb 3-1.7: Product: BCM43142A0
[   12.833448] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   12.833452] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0231
[   13.024259] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   13.024266] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   22.816476] Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm uvcvideo crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_hdmi crc32_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core btusb btrtl btbcm v4l2_common btintel videodev aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic aes_x86_64 snd_hda_intel bluetooth media lrw snd_hda_codec gf128mul snd_hda_core glue_helper snd_hwdep cfg80211 hp_wmi sparse_keymap ablk_helper snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event cryptd snd_rawmidi joydev snd_seq input_leds serio_raw lpc_ich snd_seq_device shpchp snd_timer hp_accel lis3lv02d intel_smartconnect input_polldev mei_me hp_wireless snd mei soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 psmouse i915 nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci
[   22.818601] Modules linked in: intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm uvcvideo crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_hdmi crc32_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core btusb btrtl btbcm v4l2_common btintel videodev aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic aes_x86_64 snd_hda_intel bluetooth media lrw snd_hda_codec gf128mul snd_hda_core glue_helper snd_hwdep cfg80211 hp_wmi sparse_keymap ablk_helper snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event cryptd snd_rawmidi joydev snd_seq input_leds serio_raw lpc_ich snd_seq_device shpchp snd_timer hp_accel lis3lv02d intel_smartconnect input_polldev mei_me hp_wireless snd mei soundcore mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 psmouse i915 nouveau mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci
[   44.284799] Modules linked in: xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm uvcvideo crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_hdmi crc32_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core btusb btrtl btbcm v4l2_common btintel videodev aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic aes_x86_64 snd_hda_intel bluetooth media lrw snd_hda_codec gf128mul snd_hda_core glue_helper snd_hwdep cfg80211 hp_wmi sparse_keymap ablk_helper snd_pcm snd_seq_midi
[  202.654555] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 43142, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[  202.654591] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x28, class 0x0)
[  202.654617] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x21, class 0x0)
[  202.654669] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x16, class 0x0)
[  202.654733] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: UNKNOWN (manuf 0x43B, id 0x368, rev 0x00, class 0x0)
[  202.670219] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
```

So seems it looked like some file not found, and that my HDD has been full at some point, I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I disabled the UEFI secure boot when apt-get prompted.
But it didn't solve the issue so far.
So I rebooted the computer, **went inside bios/uefi menu (F10 on my computer) and disabled the "Secure boot"**. It made the wifi working again :-)