# Wireless not Working on Dell Latitude D430 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

Please help me with my problem.

I am trying to install from [Wireless not Working on Dell Latitude D430](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301268/wireless-not-working-on-dell-latitude-d430). But I can't install and terminal is showing

```
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer
```

I think that Package is not support Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) See various answers, including [the first](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/22949), for solutions similar to the one posted here. See [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/177854/22949) for a solution that is effectively the same (the only difference being that it has an explicit `reboot` command mentioned at the end) as [the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/892577/22949).

Answer (score 3):

The package is supported and available in Ubuntu 16.04. With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.